# How to create a customized theme similar to theme_bw in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following codes in ggplot2:

```
require("ggplot2")
df <- data.frame(x=factor(rep(1:2,5)), y=rnorm(10))

ggplot(df , aes(x,y)) + geom_point(size = 3) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1, colour = "black", size=12),
      plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", hjust=0.5)) +
labs(title = "Plot")
```

Now, I want to change the background color to theme_bw, but then the main title and the x-axis options will be changed back to default.

```
ggplot(df , aes(x,y)) + geom_point(size = 3) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1, colour = "black", size=12),
      plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", hjust=0.5)) +
labs(title = "Plot") + 
theme_bw()
```

So, how can I change the theme to be the same as theme_bw but without losing other options?

Thanks

Comment: How about adding your custom themes after `theme_bw()`?

Comment: Change the order of your `theme` elements.  So change the theme to `theme_bw` first and then changing the additional theme elements after that.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Yeah, it worked. Great solution

Answer (score 9):

Here's the solution (make sure that `theme_bw()` is used before the `theme()` that you want to apply:

```
ggplot(df , aes(x,y)) + geom_point(size = 3) + 
theme_bw() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1, colour = "black", size=12),
      plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", hjust=0.5)) +
labs(title = "Plot")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @A Gore. Really smart answer. Wow.

Comment: You can also set this theme at the beginning of your script and apply it to all your plots. To do this, before doing any plots, run `theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(...))`, where the `...` is all the code inside the `theme` function. Then this new theme will automatically be applied to all subsequent plots.

Comment: @eipi Thanks, yeah, it makes things much easier

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting option would be to write a function that only updates the theme if the the theme elements are not already defined. Thus it would be similar to `+`, but themes cannot be overwritten, only added:

```
`%+safe%` <- function(e1, e2){
  if (!is.theme(e1) || !is.theme(e2)) {
    stop("%+replace% requires two theme objects", call. = FALSE)
  }

  not_in_e1 <- names(e2)[!names(e2) %in% names(e1)]
  e1[not_in_e1] <- e2[not_in_e1]
  e1
}

ggplot(df , aes(x,y)) + geom_point(size = 3) + labs(title = "Plot") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1, colour = "black", size=12),
        plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", hjust=0.5))  %+safe% theme_bw()
```

Note, this needs to take two `theme` objects so you have to move `labs()` anyway.